# Increasing system clock frequency on STM32F303 drops I2C clock proportionately - why?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c, clock, clock-speed

I'm trying to figure out a weird little issue I've discovered while [debugging another element of my code](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/466952/large-delay-between-i2c-messages-on-stm32f303-trying-to-read-as-fast-as-possib).

I've got a STM32F303K8 reading and writing to an I2C peripheral.

The I2C clock speed is configured to be 400 kHz in CubeMX, but that's not the actual clock speed when I look at it via a logic analyzer.

To make things more interesting/confusing, there seems to be an inverse relationship between the system clock speed and the actual I2C speed.

When I'm running at 8 MHz system clock (CubeMX config below):

[image: 8 MHz configuration in CubeMX]

My I2C clock looks like this on a logic analyzer:

[image: Logic analyzer trace showing I2C clock running at 333.33 kHz]

Showing 333.33 kHz.

When I change the system clock up to 72 MHz (CubeMX below):

[image: CubeMX at 72 MHz Configuration]

Logic analyzer trace of the I2C clock looks like this:

[image: Logic analyzer trace showing I2C clock speed of 46.79 kHz]

Giving me only 46.79 kHz. No other settings were changed.

My I2C settings are below (configured in 72 MHz mode - the 8 MHz mode is the same, except for the timing register).

[image: I2C Settings]

I've been trying to root out the source of this all day, with not much luck. Does anybody know what's going on here, and what I can do to prevent this causing problems?

Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the external crystal works? It almost matches a situation where the PLL can't use external crystal and the core actually runs at internal 8 MHz, not 72 MHz from PLL?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I just checked the clock on an oscilloscope and got 8Mhz on the nose from the crystal.

Comment: If the PLL is indeed working, double check that your tool is routing the clock to the I2C hardware that it thinks its routing.  Actually checking hardware registers and comparing them against the datasheet, as tedious as it sounds, should tell you what's what.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with cubemx but you should check that when you change the setting from 8 to 72 MHz you're changing the actual clock frequency and not just changing an *assumed* clock frequency that's used to calculate the I2C prescaler divider values. One way would be to flash an LED using a dumb NOP delay loop with a fixed number of iterations, note the approximate actual flash period, then change clock config and see if the flash period changes accordingly.

Comment: @pileunderflow Getting clock at the oscillator does not mean the clock was present or it has been stable since PLL was configured to use it. CSS will fall back to internal oscillator as soon as it detects clock failure.

Comment: @Justme - is there any way to detect when this happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large delay between I2C messages on STM32F303 - trying to read as fast as possible](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/466952/large-delay-between-i2c-messages-on-stm32f303-trying-to-read-as-fast-as-possib) your own recent and unresolved question on the very same overall problem.

Comment: This should be an edit providing supporting information to your existing, unresolved question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/466952/large-delay-between-i2c-messages-on-stm32f303-trying-to-read-as-fast-as-possib on the I2C issue, not a new question.  That's especially true as your existing question neither has, nor is likely to have any responses beyond wild guesses until you support it with more information such as this.

Comment: The microcontroller has a MCO (master clock out) pin that you could enable and then check the signal with your analyzer to know whether the clock is running at the intended frequency.

Comment: Chris - I decided to have it as a separate question because the delay appears to be more in the programming/implementation of the I2C - this appears (at least to me) to be more rooted in the hardware itself.

Comment: Configurators are a great tool, but not infallible.  I've had luck with ST, but Microchip's is ridiculous.

Comment: You can check that the PLL is working on the config settings by using the CLKOUT pin. CubeMX should have the MCO pin configuration somewhere, just attach that to the PLL output and measure it with the oscilloscope.